# GraphQL with Api-Platform returning null in GraphiQL

Tags: symfony, graphql, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have setup api-platform without docker in a Symfony 4 skeleton and have added GraphQL support as mentioned here - https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql

When using GraphiQL I seem to only get null responses, I have tried a lot of different GraphQL syntax, all returning null.

[Null response in GraphiQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWh2W.png)

Ive tried:

```
{
  user{
    id
  }
}
```

-

```
{
  user(id: 1){
    id
  }
}
```

-

```
{
  users(id: 1){
    id
  }
}
```

All with no luck

I can request the api normally and I get a response.

[Successful request in API tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrIqs.png)

Also, the requests in GraphiQL seem to all be post, this might be unrelated though.

Ive been trying to fix this for a while now and haven't managed to find any help online.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer for those having the same issues.

api-platform uses uuids and you have to search with this in graphql

```
query {
    user(id: "users/1"){
        firstName
        lastName
    }   
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to use plain ids using `allow_plain_identifiers: true` in api-platform config file.

Comment: @EugeneR where exactly in the config? I have that in my config/packages/api-platform.yml but it doesnt do anything. Do you know what version of api-platform i need?

Comment: hm, it is possible, that it works only with json and json-ld. Check this pr on their github - https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1365

Comment: any explanation why the query without any ID (the first one in your question) doesn't work? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Tom just incorrect syntax. You have to specify the id like in my first comment

Comment: strangely, didn't work for me. What did work is when I specified the node and edges indicators explicitly.